# Round Double According To Next Digit

Tags: java, function, double, rounding

How can I round a double according to the next digit?
For example:

1,23-->1,2

3,6544767-->3,65458

Like we know in Math. If the next digit is five or more we round it to ceiling. If it's lower than 5 we do the opposite. Also I have to do it with 5 decimals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Rounding" changes the actual value of your double.

"Display to five places" is a "presentation issue" - the number of decimal places you show in a "print" statement doesn't have to match the actual precision of your double variable.

Having said that, you might consider using [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

- It doesn't alter the underlying value
- It will display the value to 5 decimal places (if you wish)
- It can automatically round the displayed value for you
- By default, the rounding method it uses, `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`, is exactly what you described above.